# Dynamic angular material filterPredicate

Tags: angular, filter, html-table, angular-material

I want to do filterPredicate with dynamic columns, the product depends on the columns

and I add them like this:

`this.displayedColumns = Object.keys(this.fichas[0].datos);`

my object looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXCfu.png)

but it doesn't work for me any ideas?

try to do this:
`this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data, filter: string): any => {for (const prop in data.datos) { data.datos[prop].toLowerCase().includes(filter)}}`

Comment: At a first glance, it's missing any return statement. The predicate should return a boolean value indicating whether the record matches the search criteria. You just iterate the records without returning anything.